# Goku new transformation grey eyes light blue aura is it related with the other picture released?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

So a new photo of a Goku transformation has been released by a japanese magazine, a transformation we havent seen in the series yet.

[image]

But before, we got another picture of a possible Goku transformation from a Dragon Ball Super producer, he stated it was "Goku as he tries to break new ground in order to face off against the mightiest of foes in the midst of the fierce battle that is the Tournament of Power! "

[image]

So are these 2 pictures supposed to be Goku new transformation or one is and the other isnt? They have the same hair but different aura, what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: the future is near https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/3/30/Goku_SSJ5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110404193448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toei released a trailer yesterday for a TV special of Dragon Ball Super and One piece and they showed an animation of Goku's new form. So both pictures are related, and the actual Goku new form features a combination of the blue aura seen in one of the pictures, and the orange aura seen in the other picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Happy to update this when *Dragon Ball Super* tells us, but I'd have to go with the new form.

The hair is the same as you've pointed out

- New Style
- Grey-ish streaks

But also quite importantly his eyes have changed to Grey, and we have [Super Saiyan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMzC7l.jpg), [Super Saiyan God](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXYaEl.png), [Super Saiyan Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO1wwl.jpg), and [Super Saiyan Rose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGta5l.jpg) as evidence of new eye colour meaning a new form!

As to the aura, that could be just a choice made for the images to make it look good in advertising. If I had to pick one as the actual Aura, I'd pick the top image as it makes more sense for the Aura to be a close colour match the hair and eyes. I expect it may look closer to grey in *Dragon Ball Super* than it does in either of the images.